# Riverpod not updating the UI using StateNotifier and providing with stateNotifierProvider

Tags: riverpod

Im using an async function in the StateNotifier class and state is a simple class
when i hit save in the editor it shows the correct value...but not until then.

my code this:

```dart
class UserController extends stateNotifier<UserState> {
  UserController({required Databases dbs}) : _dbs= dbs , super(UserSate());
  
  Databases _dbs;

  Future<void> getUserDetails(String uid) async {
    UserDetail res = await _dbs.getDocument(uid); // some user id string
    state.Userdetail = res; 
  }
}

class UserSate {
  UserDetail? user
  bool? isloading;
}

class UserDetail {
  String? name;
  String? email;
}
```

now in the UI
after the build function I run

```dart
ref.watch(UserDetailProvider.notifier).getUserDetails("43782fake78");
text("ref.watch(UserDetailProvider).user?.name"));
```

screen loads i see null ...even through build runs ...btw its a future how do I handle this.

tried to run the function in contructor same result

Comment: just to clarify , I use stateNotofierPorivider to provide the UserController to my consumer widget. since notifyListeners is not needed, why dosent the widget update when the UserDetail state is being watched for changes...the value just get read once as null (initial value) , then when i hot save in the editor only is refreshes and show the correct value.
I have also tried changin the widget to a conumerState widget with a setState but still same result
I am aware of futureProvider but seem unnecessary...to provide a future provider for every single future function in StateNofifier class

Answer (score 0):

Your `UserState` (and `UserDetail`) model should probably be immutable and have the properly overridden `hashcode/==`. Try using the [equatable](https://pub.dev/packages/equatable) or [freezed](https://pub.dev/packages/freezed) package to create such a object.

Additional material for review:

- [Immutable Data Patterns in Dart and Flutter](https://dart.academy/immutable-data-patterns-in-dart-and-flutter/)

Comment: I will try freeing the class as you suggest.